# How to move files from FileVault to NTFS?

Tags: bootcamp, filevault, ntfs

I have a 2011 MacBook Air running Lion.

I have setup a small Boot Camp partition for the sole purpose of copying files on to NTFS hard drives. (NTFS is the only file system my media player supports that can handle large files.)

My main partition is encrypted using FileVault - this is not optional as I travel with the MacBook and my email is on there, so it has to be encrypted.

My problem is that when booting into Windows there doesn't seem to be any way to mount the FileVault protected partition!

Am I screwed or missing something obvious?

How would you move files from a FileVault encrypted Mac onto an NTFS storage device?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried moving them to a FAT32 USB disk, then using Windows to move them to your NTFS drive?

You could also try MacFUSE and NTFS-3G.

Comment: Some of my files are > 4 gb so fat32 won't work

Comment: I've looked at both MacFUSE and NTFS-3G, but can't find any packages compatible with Lion...

Comment: +1, using MacFuse/NTFS-3G (or the paid equivalent - Tuxera NTFS) works well for me on Lion.

Comment: @Chris, getting MacFuse and NTFS-3G will be tricky on Lion. I elected to use Tuxera NTFS - works very well.

Comment: @JW8 that sounds promising - which package are you using? Thanks

Comment: Oh well, paying 21 euro to use NTFS when I already own a windows license is a bitter pill. But looks like I'm out of options. Grumble....

Comment: @Chris, hopefully the MacFuse/NTFS-3G package can work with Lion soon. I used it with Snow Leopard, but had to pay for Tuxera when I upgraded my box to Lion.